# Problem using collision detection to increment the game score in SFML 2.4

Tags: c++, collision-detection, sfml

I am making a flappy bird game just to get an idea of how to make games using SFML 2.4 and C++. I have a scoring system which is supposed to increment the score by 1 everytime the bird sprite intersects with an invisible pipe. However, instead of incrementing the score by 1 the score comes to around 57 and 60. Any ideas to get this working is really appreciated.

```
int main()
{
    int score = 0;

    float PipeInvisi = 200.0;

    while(window.isOpen())
    {
        if (state == State::PLAYING)
        {
            // Setup the Invisible Pipe for Movement
            if (!PipeInvisbleActive)
            {
                // How fast is the Pipe
                spriteInvisi.setPosition(905, 0);
                PipeInvisbleActive = true;
            }
            else
            {
                spriteInvisi.setPosition(spriteInvisi.getPosition().x - (PipeInvisi * dt.asSeconds()), spriteInvisi.getPosition().y);
                // Has the pipe reached the right hand edge of the screen?
                if (spriteInvisi.getPosition().x < -165)
                {
                    // Set it up ready to be a whole new cloud next frame
                    PipeInvisbleActive = false;
                }
            }

            // Has the Bird hit the invisible pipe
            Rect<float> Birdie = spriteBird.getGlobalBounds();
            Rect<float> Paipu5 = spriteInvisi.getGlobalBounds();
            if (Birdie.intersects(Paipu5))
            {
                // Update the score text
                score++;
                std::stringstream ss;
                ss << "Score = " << score;
                scoreText.setString(ss.str());
                clock.restart();
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Please post [minimal, complete and verifiable](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) example. It's hard to draw any conclusions from your code at the moment, but if I had to guess it's possible that you're incrementing the counter each frame the objects intersect, not only when they start to intersect.

Comment: I figured as much. Do you have sample code or resource that shows how to only increment at the moment they intersect?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming that your problem stems from constant intersection, you could introduce a simple flag that marks the intersection.

```cpp
bool isBirdIntersectingPipe = false;
```

Then in your game loop you could detect the beginning of intersection like so.

```cpp
if (birdRect.intersects(pipeRect)) // Intersection this frame.
{
    if (!isBirdIntersectingPipe) // No intersection last frame, so this is the beginning.
    {
        ++score;
        isBirdIntersectingPipe = true;
    }

    // Still intersecting, so do nothing.
}
else // No intersection this frame.
{
    isBirdIntersectingPipe = false;
}
```

Ideally you would have a dedicated collision or even physics system that would track all objects on the scene, but in this case a simple solution like this should suffice.

Comment: This is exactly what I was looking for. Thank you for saving me a few hours and teaching me something new. Works Perfectly.